# PS: Define multiple variables in File1, read File2, and replace all tags in File1 with the variables in File2

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a file1 with several variables defined:

```
    '$GateWay_HostName'='Biscuits'
    '$DomainName'='AND'
    '$DC_Name'='Gravy'
```

I have another file (File2) with line by line commands to send to Cisco devices. I do not want to read file, replace variables, then save file, because the passwords will be entered in cleartext. I can't seem to figure out how to import the variables and replace any matching string with the value.

I can pull in the variables and call them in the script and reference $GateWay_HostName for example with:

`$ReplaceVars = Get-Content "C:\folder\file1.csv" | ConvertFrom-StringData`

But I can't seem to find anything about going through the imported string to replace all of the variables (some appear once, some appear many, some don't exist).

`$CommandstoSend = (Get-Content -Path "C:\folder\File2" -raw)`

Because the code to execute the commands are passed as raw, it won't read the variables on the fly. I need to import the raw data otherwise plink won't pass the commands, but I don't care when it gets converted to "raw". Also, if I'm going to end up using a search and replace, I know I don't need to have $VARIABLEname format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$ReplaceVars = Get-Content "C:\folder\file1.csv" -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData
$replaceString = ($ReplaceVars.Keys |% {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
[regex]::Replace((Get-Content file2 -raw),$replaceString,{param($m) $ReplaceVars[$m.Value]})
```

Using `-Raw` on `Get-Content` creates a single string. This is important for returning a single hash table after piping into `ConvertFrom-StringData`. Without `-Raw`, `ConvertFrom-StringData` outputs an array of hash tables, making lookups more complex.

`[regex]::Escape()` is to escape special regex characters like `$` that could be in your variable names. Joining on `|` creates a regex alternation (equivalent to logical OR).

The `[regex]::Replace()` method allows for a script block to be used in the replacement string parameter. Using a parameter `$m`, we can reference the object that contains the matched text (stored in the `Value` property) and manipulate it. Here we use it as a key name (`$m.Value`) for the `$replaceVars` hash table.

Effectively, this solution looks for text that matches a hash table key name and then replaces that name with the corresponding hash table value.

---

IMO, the better solution is to configure `file2` to be a template file. You can use string format placeholders where the substitutions need to happen. Then just use the string format operator `-f`. See below for an example:

```
# file2 contents
$file2 = @'
My DC Name = {0}
Domain Name = {1}
I don't want to edit this line.
Gateway Host = {2}
'@

$file2 -f 'Gravy','AND','Biscuits'
```

**Output:**

```
My DC Name = Gravy
Domain Name = AND
I don't want to edit this line.
Gateway Host = Biscuits
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm following your better solution... I have between 400-800 lines that need to be "searched" across several files. The "placement" of the variables (DC_Name) can be any line and appear more than once.